# A6627SJP-T datasheet

Tags: datasheet, servo

i have this A6627 component in the printer. Looks like a current control circuit. Does anybody have a datasheet or at least knows the serial protocol this device uses?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I am after the same data sheet. I've emailed some of the suppliers and just waiting to here back.
Were you able to get the data sheet or work out the serial protocol?

Comment: No, actually i gave up. I decided that this is just some smart H-bridge and i will not really benefit from its decoding.

Comment: cool thanks. where you able to find a suitable replacement for that IC? the main spec im after is the frequency range of the constant current PWM. in my project i want to use the linear encoder, motor and the drive train from the printer.

Comment: No, but i think it was like tens of khz on osciloscope. I will take look later.

Answer (score 1):

[This vendor](http://www.ic2ic.com/search.jsp?sSearchWord=A6627SJPT&prefix=A) seems to list it as an Allegro part. None of their "datasheet" links work, so searching for it on [AllegroMicro.com](http://www.allegromicro.com/SearchResults.aspx?q=6627&x=0&y=0)... results in nothing either. So they are either an old discontinued part, or they purposely have omitted the datasheet. Here is their [Technical Support](http://www.allegromicro.com/en/Design-Center/Technical-Assistance.aspx) contact info.

If this had to be decoded without the datasheet, "snoop" on the data traffic using something like the [Saleae Logic Analyzer](https://www.saleae.com/). It can automatically decode SPI, I2C, serial , 1-Wire, UNI/O, I2S/PCM, MP Mode, Manchester, DMX-512, Parallel, JTAG, LIN, Atmel SWI, MDIO, BiSS C, HDLC, HDMI CEC, USB 1.1 etc., with even more planned.

Comment: Yeah, i am trying to avoid bus sniffing :) probably, this is a printer specific component, so the datasheet is secret...